# Не отображается кириллица в редакторе чертежа в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, utf-8, кодировка, кириллица

После обновления Android Studio до сборки AI-162.3764568 и Android SDK tools до 25.3.1 перестала корректно отображаться кириллица в визуальном редакторе активности, при чем только в виде blueprint, в виде design все нормально. До обновления в обоих видах отображалось корректно. Кодировка файлов utf-8. В коде и в прочих местах IDE все ок.

[image: скриншот области дизайна]

Comment: да глюк какой-то. потом исправят, наверное. Особенно если в багрепорт отписать

Comment: Да, если никто идей не предложит, отправлю багрепорт, сенкс